# What would happen if a tungsten rod massing 1000kg slammed into the surface of Callisto at 15% of the speed of light?

Tags: physics, geology

I am writing a sci fi story and I want to know what would happen if a tungsten rod massing 1000kg slammed into the surface of Callisto at 15% of the speed of light? Given that there is a subsurface ocean what would the impact look like from afar, say half a million kms? Would there be a blinding light and steam and ejecta?

Specifically, I am interested in the visual effects and effects felt by residents moon wide. The target is a city built inside of Tindr crater on Callisto. Would there be moon-wide quakes? How long would quakes last? What would be the damage done to subsurface infrastructure? Would it penetrate deep enough to open a hole to the subsurface saltwater ocean? Also how would the explosion behave in vacuum?

Comment: Just so nobody else does the same calculation: KE of tungsten rod ≈ 10^18 J; binding energy of Callisto ≈ 2 × 10^29 J. So we're not talking moon-shattering effects, at least.   Also, for comparison, the yield of Tsar Bomba was about 2 × 10^17 J according to Wikipedia, or about 1/5 of the energy we're talking about here.  But that was detonated in atmosphere, so I would expect the results to be different if a comparable amount of energy was suddenly delivered to the surface of Callisto.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Tsar Bomba was also a surface explosion, not an impactor.  MUCH more of the energy gets delivered into the moon's ice crust than would be the case with a fusion bomb on the surface.

Comment: This reads like a physics question, not a question about building a fictional world.

Comment: Worth noting that the usual reason one uses tungsten for these things (high melting point prevents ablation when powering through an atmosphere) would be somewhat irrelevant here.

Comment: If you'd told us about the effect you wanted to achieve, then asked for our help to achieve it, I suspect there wouldn't have been the close votes.

Comment: Once you hit energies like these, the composition and trajectory of the impactor become irrelevant. Angle of impact, irrelevant. All that matters is a neat spherical explosion remarkably like a nuke, that occurs just below the surface (less than 100 m penetration). Only of there is a significant atmosphere does the air transit matter, and that is mostly for cosmetic effect not so much a change in the energies. So use any old nuke modeler, if will be spot-on, except minimal residual radioactivity.

Comment: @ZeissIkon So strange to hear 4000 meters above the terrain described as "a surface explosion".

Comment: @PcMan As opposed to an impactor...

Comment: @sphennings If he just wanted to know blast radius and energy output, I may agree, but since he wants details about what it will look like, how it will feel in other places on the moon, etc... those go into other realms than pure physics.  This question requires a combination of physics, geology, history, and astronomy to answer; so, I would not move it to any other SE, because anyone of those SEs would label this as too broad or off topic.  I would call this World Building because he has an event that redefines his environment, and needs to know how it would be redefined.

Comment: Tindr Crater? Like, has the IAU started selling naming rights to these things or something?

Comment: @PcMan I disagree on the angle of impact not mattering.  The energy is going to be directional--that kinetic energy has to go somewhere.  If it hits straight in you get a round crater, if it hits almost parallel to the surface you get a long gouge.

Comment: @LorenPechtel remember that the kinetic energy is *not* directional. It simply exists. The *momentum* is very directional, but is a trivial component of the activity at the energy scales we are working with here.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert that calculation is a good start, but at 0.15 c we have to take into account the tungsten fusing with the elements it impacts. Tungsten is heavier than iron so energy will be lost, but I don't know how to calculate how much.

Comment: @sphennings:  For context, this was originally posted over in Physics, and it was closed with the suggestion that it be re-posted here.  (As a user of both boards, I tend to think it's a better fit here.)

Comment: Push it up to .999c and we got a question!

Answer (score 10):

At about 250 megatons, the resulting energy would be about 10 times greater than the Mt. Saint Helens Volcanic Eruption.  This would be enough energy to launch a mass of debris equal to a large mountain into the air, and at only 0.126G, a significant portion of it would be able to exceed escape velocity flying off into space.

Calisto has a very minimal atmosphere and no molten core. If it has a subsurface ocean, it is believed to be at a depth of 100–150km.  So, the impact would not have very interesting interactions with the things above or below the moon's crust.

The crust itself is about a 1:1 ratio of silicon rich rock and ice.  It is likely that most of the ice would melt or vaporize on impact.  So, I would expect to see an explosion that looks like a cross between an [underground nuclear test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underground_nuclear_weapons_testing) and an [underwater nuclear test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underwater_explosion) does during the early phase of the explosion, but instead of mushrooming off as gravity and air resistance slow the blast down, the explosion will mostly just get bigger and bigger until is dissipates leaving only a small amount of the debris to fall back onto the moon or settle into an orbiting ring of dust.

Mt. Saint Helens could be heard from >250 miles away.  Even at 10 times this strong, the impact may not be heard or felt from everywhere on the moon, but could certainly be felt from very far away.  That said, there may be other factors at play that allow the energy to propagate better or worse. In general shockwaves travel much better through solid rock or liquid water than they do through ice, sand, or clay. Also, your impactor is imparting all of its energy at once, not over a long time like a volcano; so, you may get a stronger seismic wave that is over quickly compared to Mt. Saint Helens. Given the Kracatoa eruption as cited by JobSG in comments, I will say it is at least possible that it would be felt across the whole moon, but very hard to say for sure given limited information available for the moon's exact geology.

Based on nuclear tests which follow a similar profile to this impact, the initial flash of light will be very bright, but only last 1-3 seconds before being obscured by the debris cloud.  The Earthquake, will probably last less than a minute, but will take longer the farther you are from the blast.  This is because surface waves and sub-surface waves travel at different speeds. At some distances, it may even feel like two or more distinct earthquakes.  You will not get days worth of aftershocks like you do from seismic events here on Earth though because Calisto is seismically inert; so, there would be no settling period in the plate techtonics.

As for the city built inside of Tindr crater,  https://nuclearweaponsedproj.mit.edu/ estimated:

@ 13.3km: Heavily built concrete buildings are severely damaged or demolished

@ 18.7 km: Reinforced concrete buildings are severely damaged or demolished. Most people are killed.

@ 27.8 km: Most buildings collapse. Injuries are universal, fatalities are widespread.

Now there is the huge caveat here of the atmosphere making a difference which you will need to answer.  Namely: what are those colonist breathing?  If your colony is contained inside of some giant atmosphere containing dome structure, then these estimates will be pretty accurate since your colonists will have given the impactor a good medium to propagate its shockwave through.

If your structures are surface level self contained units, then the shockwave will be much less significant, but the thermal and gamma energy will still devastate the whole area. In an atmosphere, most surface level buildings and people within about 6.7km would be incinerated by the blast, but without an atmosphere to convert all those high energy gamma rays into thermal radiation, it is very possible that everyone in the 70km wide crater will receive a fatal dose of gamma rays.  Those who do not die right away are in for a long and agonizing death, even if their buildings survive.

If you are building underground, then you may fair much better.  A 1.2 megaton B83 warhead (the highest yield Robust Nuclear Earth Penetrator (RNEP) in the U.S. nuclear stockpile) can destroy underground bunkers to a depth of about 300 meters. A penetrator with 208 times as much energy would have around a 1200 meter kill radius; so, your subterranean structures near the impact area will likely all be caved in unless they go very deep, but even relatively shallow subterranean structures beyond a radius of 1.2km will have a decent chance of survival.

Comment: It would however be detectable everywhere on Calisto by even simple sensors, very quickly everyone on the body will know something very bad happened.

Comment: The radius of Callisto is 1500 miles. The Kracatoa explosion (200 megatons) was heard 1900 miles away and was still detectable after crossing the planet 4 times. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krakatoa

Comment: The blast effects you list are due to the shock wave propagated via Earth's atmosphere.  Pressure on Callisto is about 7 trillionths of Earth pressure and are not comparable.  My guess is that the fireball radius would be about 10 km and heat sufficient to cause 3rd degree burns up to about 100 miles from ground zero extrapolating from the calculated effects of the Tsar Bomb. More than enough for a bad day in Tindr Town.

Comment: @GaryWalker fireball is a vacuum would be close to nonexistent. The fireball in the surface material itself will be smaller and brighter due to higher density material, but will be very much self-shielding, only visible from above. You will get a *very* sharp groundshock, and in that low gravity a quite ludicrously large ejecta plume. Quite possibly large enough to temporarily give Jupiter a short-lived ring in Callisto's orbit

Comment: @PcMan - yes, no atmosphere no fireball (atmosphere hearted to incandescence), but the thermal radiation levels equivalent to a fireball will still be present. As the superhot ejecta from the impact spreads rises it will cook the area without atmosphere. Ground shock will be devastating to underground structures that could escape the the thermal effects.

Comment: @GaryWalker Good point on the atmosphere, I've added some alternate possible outcomes depending on how the city is built.

Comment: @GaryWalker I don't think the thermal energy will be very important as nobody is going to simply be walking around on Callisto.  They'll be inside something, the thermal pulse will expend itself against that something.  Unless that something is as minor as a spacesuit or the like I don't think they'll care.

Comment: @GaryWalker Now that you mention it, the thermal energy is not nearly as as deadly as the gamma ray burst that you would get in a vacuum.  Without an atmosphere, to convert Gamma Rays into heat, the kill radius of a nuke significantly increases. Especially against thermally insulated structures. https://history.nasa.gov/conghand/nuclear.htm

Comment: @Nosajimiki - My first thought was what gamma ray burst? This is not a nuke, nor an air-burst. OTOH, at .15c the collision is sufficient overcome the coulomb barrier and initiate fusion reactions during impact.

Answer (score -3):

I don't think you would get a flash when it hit. You would get a small one that would be obscured by all the particles that it would throw up. You may crack the surface enouph to let out sub surface water and produce a ploom of "snow" but it would freeze again.

The area it hit would be flash boiled and you would have multiple quakes. Some from the initial hit and some as the earth waves move through the surface from the other side of the planet.

Sub surface tunnels would probably collapse depending on how they are made.

Edit: Oh and perhaps I should clarify. If it penetrates too deeply then any flash will be hidden by the ice around it. Infra red may show more.

It would just create a new crater. Nothing special after the dust settles.

Also if you are on the other side of the planet from the hit you won't see it (for obvious reasons).

Comment: you absolutely get a flash, as rock is superheated, light travels faster than particles.

Comment: https://science.nasa.gov/science-news/science-at-nasa/2013/16may_lunarimpact

Comment: @John You would get a very bright flash indeed. But almost no-one will see it from the surface, as it will be at the bottom of a shallow crater, and shielded from view on the sides by its own ejecta.

Comment: @PcMan that's not how impact flashes work, the light has been emitted before the ejecta can actually move, in fact that's part of the reason why the flash occurs, because matter is incapable of moving fast enough to dissipate the energy. there is no crater nor ejecta at the instant the flash occurs. in the following micro-seconds the ejecta itself emits even more light.

Comment: @john the flash occurs at, and *below* the surface. If will get a very hefty mount of shielding to observers ***ON THE SURFACE***

Comment: Gathris, boy, what are u doing here, lol.

Comment: @MolbOrg I can't comment on others answers till my rep improves so to improve it I have to submit my own answers and take the flack if my thinking on a subject is not well thought out.

Comment: @Nosajimiki The light there is not stated as visible light, It is "thermal glow of molten rock" so more infra red.

Comment: @Gathris yeah was there, a tip take ahy magic related question, there is enough of thise, and ther ee u basicall need nothing but fantasy, if it coherent nobody even  notice anything. Those or somwthing like that https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/low-fantasy does not matter hiw old itis, it will popup on front page and if u have good fantasy and there are few answers u get some rep

Comment: @Gathris The observation from my link can be made with a normal telescope because rock heated up enough glows in the visible spectrum. When impact energies are this high, it's like the glowing sparks you get when you use an angle grinder on steel.  In the case of a relativistic impact as the OP requested, you don't just get glowing molten rock, you get a blast of superheated plasma which will give you a full range of wavelengths ranging all the way up to gamma rays.